# is there a way to resize the project tool window of intellij on a mac?

Tags: intellij-idea

The showing of the .java content is a little too big for my liking. Unlike most IDE's that have such feature under view, the Intellij seems to have it hidden. [image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly are you trying to resize?

Comment: Check that you are not in "Zen" mode or "Distraction free" mode. Use Cmd+1 to open project tool window.